# How to sort a string by a number in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have an array of strings that each start with a number

I'm trying to sort the array from greatest to least using the number in back of each string

So far I have tryed copying off the numbers from the string, then sorting the numbers, looping through the original array to find the number that matched the sorted numbers, and placing the full original string in that place. This way the original strings would end up in the same order of the sorted numbers, but this did not work.

How can I do this?

--

Input array:

"Ticker symbol |1|| " , "Ticker symbol |5|| " , "Ticker symbol |2|| " ,

Output desired:

"Ticker symbol |1|| " , "Ticker symbol |2|| " , "Ticker symbol |5|| " ,

--

The Code so far

```
//@version=5
indicator("sorting strings by number in string")


tickerstring1 = "Ticker symbol " + "|" + str.tostring(1) + "||"

tickerstring2 = "Ticker symbol " + "|" + str.tostring(5) + "||"

tickerstring3 = "Ticker symbol " + "|" + str.tostring(2) + "||"

string[] arrayofstrings = array.from(tickerstring1, tickerstring2, tickerstring3)


tickerstring1posstart = str.pos(tickerstring1, "|")
tickerstring1posend = str.pos(tickerstring1, "||")

tickerstring2posstart = str.pos(tickerstring1, "|")
tickerstring2posend = str.pos(tickerstring1, "||")

tickerstring3posstart = str.pos(tickerstring1, "|")
tickerstring3posend = str.pos(tickerstring1, "||")



numberfromstringtickerstring1 = str.substring(tickerstring1, tickerstring1posstart, tickerstring1posend)
numberfromstringtickerstring2 = str.substring(tickerstring2, tickerstring2posstart, tickerstring2posend)
numberfromstringtickerstring3 = str.substring(tickerstring3, tickerstring3posstart, tickerstring3posend)


string[] listofnumbersfromstrings = array.from(numberfromstringtickerstring1, numberfromstringtickerstring2, numberfromstringtickerstring3)


array.sort(listofnumbersfromstrings, order.descending)

listofnumbersfromstringstouseablearray = str.split(  str.tostring(listofnumbersfromstrings), ",")


finaluseablearraynumbers = str.split(  str.tostring(  listofnumbersfromstringstouseablearray   ), ",")


indicatorstring = "a"

for i = 0 to 2

    for a = 0 to 2

        if ( str.tostring(listofnumbersfromstringstouseablearray[i])  == str.tostring(finaluseablearraynumbers[a])  )
            indicatorstring := str.tostring(arrayofstrings[a])


//
labelname = label.new(bar_index,0,  ( indicatorstring )  , color=color.yellow, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_down, size=size.large, yloc=yloc.price)


//
label.delete(labelname[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by using [array.sort_indices()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array%7Bdot%7Dsort_indices)
This is a working example, based on your input.

```
//@version=5
indicator("sorting strings by number in string")

f_buildString(int _nr) => str.format('Ticker symbol |{0}||', _nr)

f_getNrFromString(string _str, string  _startStr = '|', string  _endStr = '||') =>
    posStart = str.pos(_str, _startStr) + 1
    posEnd   = str.pos(_str, _endStr)
    str.tonumber(str.substring(_str, posStart, posEnd))
   
var string      tickerstring1               = f_buildString(1) //"Ticker symbol " + "|" + str.tostring(1) + "||"
var string      tickerstring2               = f_buildString(5)
var string      tickerstring3               = f_buildString(2)
var string      tickerstring4               = f_buildString(99)
var string      tickerstring5               = f_buildString(20)
var string      tickerstring6               = f_buildString(15)

var string[]    arrayofstrings              = array.from(tickerstring1, tickerstring2, tickerstring3, tickerstring4, tickerstring5, tickerstring6)
var float[]     listofnumbersfromstrings    = array.new<float>()

var label       myLabel                     = label.new(na, na, color=color.yellow, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_down, size=size.large, yloc=yloc.price)

if barstate.isfirst
    for myStr in arrayofstrings
        array.push(listofnumbersfromstrings, f_getNrFromString(myStr))

if barstate.islast
    string labelText = ''
    sortedIndices = array.sort_indices(listofnumbersfromstrings, order.ascending)
    for idx in sortedIndices
        labelText += (idx==0 ? '' : '\n') + array.get(arrayofstrings, idx)
    label.set_xy(myLabel, bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(myLabel, labelText)
```

Which yields

[image: output image]

Comment: Thank You, it works.  Sometimes when the first variable is not in the top of the sorted pile, it end up next to another string instead of on a new line. I fixed this by changing the "labelText += (idx==0 ? '' : '\n') + array.get(arrayofstrings, idx)" Line to "    labelText += ('\n') + array.get(arrayofstrings, idx)" . Thanks!